# Adding "owner" field in gitolite gitweb?

Tags: gitolite

I am trying to add an owner name of repo that shows up on gitweb.
I can't seem to find anything on the net.

Anybody knows how to do it?

I know to change the description of repo by ssh git@server desc reponame "string"

But, there seems nothing for owner.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)** and **[gitweb](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb)** are two different tools:

- gitolite is an [authorization layer](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#auth) in perl (which [can be integrated to gitweb](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitweb-daemon.html)).
  it needs to be installed *in addition* of Git, and be called from one of the listeners (httpd or sshd) which does the authentication.
- **[gitweb](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/gitweb.txt)** is a web interface, part of the Git distribution.

A repo as stored on a Git hosting server is not "owned" by a user.
It only has in gitolite a list of users who are authorized to push to it.

The [**`gitweb.perl`**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb.perl) perl script does try to [get the ownership information](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7974889a053574e449b55ca543a486e38e74864f/gitweb/gitweb.perl#L3233-L3255), based on, for instance, a `git config owner` property attached to the repo. Or from the folder owner.

None of those information are native to a Git repo hosting server, and you need to make sure the right owner is registered somehow (with, for example, adding that config to the repo, [which can be set with Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/git-config/))

In any case, you would need to make sure [$omit_owner is not set to 1](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7974889a053574e449b55ca543a486e38e74864f/gitweb/gitweb.perl#L151-L152).

Answer (score 0):

short answer is

1. edit the `$GIT_CONFIG_KEYS` option in the [gitolite rc](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/rc#specific-variables) file to include `gitweb.owner` and/or `gitweb.description`.
2. in your gitolite.conf, for example:

```
repo hello-world
    RW+     =   me
    R       =   @all
    config gitweb.owner   =   "my name [my-email@riseup.net]"
    config gitweb.description    =   "hello world desc"
```

Notes:

- the dot should be escaped with `\` in the .rc file
- for whatever reason using pointy bracket for the `<email>` is recognized as "bad config value", so I'm using `[]` here.